# Tailwind CSS works locally but doesn't work on GitHub Pages

Tags: tailwind-css, github-pages

I made a static site with Tailwind CSS and it's working locally but it's not working on GitHub Pages. I don't know what to do. Pls help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a link to your Github Pages website so we could check what's wrong ?

A hint : Check in your console if your stylesheet link is wrong or isn't found. I'd guess on an absolute path pointing to root, instead of a relative path, but it's a wild guess without more info about your code.

Comment: You mean my GitHub repo? And I think it could be the stylesheet link but what do you mean by absolute path pointing to root and relative path?

Comment: Absolute path pointing to root (usually when you develop locally) would be http://localhost:4200/assets/css/tailwind.css or something like that) which doesn’t work when you deploy your website. And a relative path would be something like ../assets/css/tailwind.css

Comment: I did this and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it worked. Can you please vote for the answer that helped you so this question could be marked as answered/resolved ? It may help other users.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue after a fresh install of the recent Next version (combining Tailwind into the build). Locally it looks fine and I can see all styles, but after it is published on Pages, no styles are applied. I see warnings in the console that some scripts have failed to load, but I don't see any absolute paths. I don't have an html file either where I could update the stylesheet link. Any idea what else could be checked?